# How to prove that quantum computers can't solve problems outside PSPACE quickly?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-spin, quantum-computer

What are general methods to prove that certain complexity class is not proper superset of PSPACE class, and how to apply them in quantum case (for BQP class, for example).

Answer (score 2):

A PSPACE machine can simulate any BQP machine by using path integrals.

Since quantum computers are like BQP machines, and BQP is a subset of PSPACE, quantum computers can't efficiently solve problems outside of PSPACE.

Comment: Can you please explain what path integral is intended for, and how ability to use it proves or disproves what I ask?

Comment: @LeonKigelman Every quantum operation is a matrix multiplication. Instead of storing the full vectors and doing the huge matrix multiplications, you iterate over all of the ways each input amplitude can go through those matrices to reach a specific output. Once you've summed all of those up, you have one output amplitude. Square it to get a probability, and use that to decide whether this is the one to return or else move on to the next amplitude. This takes a lot more time than the matrix multiplications, but only polynomial space.

Comment: Can you suggest a good book about path integral and quntum complexity classes?